# How many flags of 8 horizontal stripes?

Tags: combinatorics

How many flags of 8 horizontal stripes are there that contain at least 6 blue stripes if each stripe is coloured red, green or blue?

I have just started combinatorics and I am supposed to do this problem without using nPr or nCr.

I am only supposed to use the addition, multiplication and the bijection principles.

Comment: Form 3 cases -- 1.) For 6 blue stripes, 2.) For 7 blue stripes, 3.) For 8 blue stripes. Find the number of possible ways for each case.

Comment: @Utkarsh There is only 1 case for 8 blue stripes, 8 cases if there are 7 blue stripes, but how do I find it for 6 blue stripes?

Comment: Try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Be careful: If there are seven blue stripes, there are $8$ ways to choose the location of the stripe that is not blue and $2$ ways to choose its color.